# Using submodel accessor (STI) on parent params for nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters, jsonb, cocoon-gem

i have the following models:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
class Bill < Order
class Preorder < Order

class Detail < ApplicationRecord
class Metric < Detail
class Unit < Detail
```

the model `Order` accept nested attributes for `Detail`, an `Order` can be a `Bill` or a `Preorder` and `Detail` can be by `Unit` or by `Metric`

i'm using jsonb_accessor gem to create additional attributes for `Unit` and `Metric`

```
class Metric < Detail
    jsonb_accessor :data,
      height: :decimal,
      width: :decimal
end

class Unit < Detail
    jsonb_accessor :data,
      quantity: :decimal
end
```

in my view, i'm using Cocoon gem to generate fields for `Unit` or `Metric`

```
<%= link_to_add_association(I18n.t('activerecord.models.metric.add'), f, :details, data: {association_insertion_node: '#details', association_insertion_method: :append}, :class => "btn btn-success", 
wrap_object: Proc.new { |detail| detail.type = "Metric"; detail = Metric.new }) %>
<%= link_to_add_association(I18n.t('activerecord.models.unit.add'), f, :details, data: {association_insertion_node: '#details', association_insertion_method: :append}, :class => "btn btn-success",
wrap_object: Proc.new { |detail| detail.type = "Unit"; detail = Unit.new }) %>
```

and in my controller, i have this method to verify the params

```
def order_params(type)
  if type=="Bill"
    params.require(:bill).permit(:client_id, :type, :delivered, :paid, :total_paid, details_attributes: [:id, :total_price, :type, :data, :service_id, :_destroy])
  elsif type=="Preorder"
    params.require(:preorder).permit(:client_id, :type, :delivered, details_attributes: [:id, :total_price, :type, :data, :service_id, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

the form works near perfectly, it store all data i put in the form except for `:width, :height, :quantity`, when i put them in params, it give an error saying that these params do not belong to Detail model and when i put `:data` instead, the column still empty.

i'm considering, using column directly for parent model `Detail` instead of using jsonb_accessor, or separate views and controller for each `Metric` and `Unit` models but i keep these solutions as last resort because i want to keep the code Dryier and use less columns as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho the problem is you are using the association `details` which means that rails is trying to create/save a `Detail`. Instead you will have to use the respective associations for `units` and `metrics` so rails knows to create the correct object which has the respective `jsonb_accessors` to save correctly.

You can just add the associations in the model:

```
has_many :metrics 
has_many :units
```

I get this is possibly not as clean in your UI (if everything is a detail you can just add/list them together). Another alternative is define all possible json-fields in your `Detail` model (but not entirely sure if that defeats the purpose of using them in the first place).

Comment: it worked, i added `has_many` association for both metrics and units as you suggested and also replaced `:data` in `details_parameters` by `:quantity`, `:widht` and `:height`. for the UI you are right, with metrics width and height inputs are not at the same lines but this problem is from simple-form-bootstrap wrappers. and about to put all field in details table it can be a problem if later i could add a new detail type for exemple `Duration < Detail` which have time as attribute, then i must create new migration to add the column time to details table. so i choosed jsonb for more flexibility